# ionic range cannot click on ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, range, ionic-framework

I am using ionic "range" input in a cross platform project.
For android and PC browser, if I click on the area away from the slider node, the slider node will jump to the point I click and the value will be updated.

But for IOS, when I click the area away from the slider node, no value change is happening. And this also make my slider difficult to click, I need to click very accurate right on the slider node, else the slider will not slide.
Any idea?

Comment: the iOS interface usually does not use any traditional side or bottom sliders for the page scrolling, so which kind of slider are we talking about exactly?

Comment: I am talking about the ionic input with type "range" For example: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range

Comment: I found the same problem even in browser. If I use iPad safari to play with the above example, click in area away from the slider wouldn't work. By it work in my mac safari.

Comment: I've had similar issues on mobile browsers. I solved it by using noUiSlider, worked on mobile for me.

Comment: noUISlider is not working with angular ionic

Answer (score 13):

I believe I have found a solution for this. Add on-tap() to your element like so:

```
    <div class="range">
        <input type="range" on-tap="onTap($event)" ng-model="barProgress" min="0" max="100">
    </div>
```

Then add this in your controller (or feel free to make a directive out of it)

```
    $scope.onTap = function(e) {
      if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        $scope.barProgress = (e.target.max / e.target.offsetWidth)*(e.gesture.touches[0].screenX - e.target.offsetLeft);
      }
    };
```

Essentially what you are doing is calculating the position of the tap relative to the screen, and then adjusting the value to work with the slider, to get the actual input value that it *would* have been. Then you update the model.

**EDIT:** This will only work with click/tap event. To make it more smooth and natural, we need to enable swipe/dragging on slider tracks too. Very simple fix will allow devs to do this. Just add on-drag="onTap($event)" so that your html look like this.

```
<div class="range">
    <input type="range" on-tap="onTap($event)" on-drag="onTap($event)" ng-model="barProgress" min="0" max="100">
</div>
```

Comment: Highly recommend this answer. Dragging on slider track still not working but is really a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, it might be possible to detect the difference between tap and drag. If it is a drag event, then you don't update the $scope.barProgress.

Comment: What about adding on-drag="onTap($event)" too? It works pretty well on my side.

Comment: @devmaniac the point I would raise is that the onTap function does *not* need to run on the on-drag event. Its doing unnecessary computations, surely? Simply we need to prevent onTap() from running if its on-drag

Comment: @CarbonDry, are you really sure on-drag works when user taps on the slider track? Can we get tap events with only on-drag handler?

Answer (score 0):

I found another option to make it work too, but using (ionBlur).

```
<ion-range min=“0” max=“100” #seeker (ionBlur)=“positionPress($event, seeker.value)” [(ngModel)]=“positionbar”>
```