# HTML <input> with type="range" not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, angularjs

I have created an HTML field as follows -

```
<input type="range" min="140000" max="1000000">
```

Now, I can slide the icon or just tap anywhere on the slider bar to select a value. This works perfectly on all browsers except on iOS. 
On iOS, the sliding function works perfectly, but nothing happens if I tap anywhere on the slider.

I found that someone faced a similar issue - [ionic range cannot click on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845263/ionic-range-cannot-click-on-ios) but this an angular.js based solution. Can this issue be resolved using pure JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: please put your minimum code in plunker, you can use onclick event in javascript.